# NPM Gulp > retrieve SCSS import filepaths

Tags: css, npm, sass, gulp

So currently in my gulp setup I have many several CSS files that are produced - a general 'core' one, and then template specific stylesheets.

Rather than re-compiling all stylesheets on each change, it only compiles the required ones - but this has led to complex "watch" paths, covering many files which just reflects whats in the primary SCSS files for each template (which consist of @use/@import statements).

Then it occured to me, wouldn't it be nice that rather than writing out all the watch filepaths, that I simply 'crawl' the SCSS file and grab all the filepaths for any @use/@import statements recursively.

So as an example, lets say I have this "blog.scss" file:

```
    // Variables 
    @import 'variables';
    
    // Tools
    @import './tools';
    
    // Parts
    @import './core/base';
    @import './templates/blog';
```

Is it possible to grab all of the filepaths for its @import statements, so e.g.:

```
'local-dev/styles/variables.scss'
'local-dev/styles/tools.scss'
'local-dev/styles/core/base.scss'
'local-dev/styles/templates/blog.scss'
```

I've considered simply retrieving the file as a string, and using some regex - but that wouldn't take file extensions into consideration (.scss/.css/_partials.scss) and would likely have other issues.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi ;) 

Do I understand correctly - you wanna interactively build only files that were changed, and do not parse>compile>build files that remained untouched?

Comment: @ve1ikiy In a sense yes. Currently my setup has 7 stylesheets for various different templates - rather than watching the whole folder, and re-creating all 7 stylesheets each time I've gone for specific watch commands - but it's proving a pain to maintain as e.g. new SCSS imports are added. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Yes, in v4 of gulp there is new API call -> [lastRun](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/lastrun/) which helps to create functions that would execute only if there are some difference from previous run. 

I will describe it in more details in answer bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you trying to achieve called incremental build system, it means - `we compile only those files, that were changed, and don't touch anything else`.

If you wanna dig into details, I really recommend this article -> [Incremental SASS Builds with Gulp](https://www.sarthakbatra.com/blog/incremental-sass-builds-with-gulp/) by Sarthak Batra.

---

If you just wanna ready2go solution, here it is:

1. All code examples are for gulpJS v4, so make sure it's the version you currently have by running console command in your project directory -> `gulp -v`
2. Aside from gulpV4 you also need to install [gulp-dependents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dependents) plugin. You can do it by running console command: `npm i --save-dev gulp-dependents` in your project folder.
3. In your gulpfile.js you need to add new import statement. For v4 it would look something like: `const dependents = require("gulp-dependents")`
4. Lastly, you need to update your gulp styles function, and make sure it would only compile changed files.

```
function styles(callMeBack) {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.styles.src, { since: gulp.lastRun(styles) })
    .pipe(dependents())
    .pipe(scss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    .on("end", callMeBack)
}
```

- `path.styles.src` -> path to your styles folder, in my case it looks like `"app/static/styles/**/*.scss"`;
- `since: gulp.lastRun(styles)` -> gulpV4 API call, that checks if current blob is the same as on the last function run, and takes into pipeline only changed files;
- `.dependents()` -> runs a [deep search with regExp](https://github.com/thomas-darling/gulp-dependents#configuration) and finds files dependent on one current one in pipeline. It's exactly what you were trying to describe in original question;
- and I think you familiar with what `.scss()` and `gulp.dest` are doing. :)
- End result -> only the styles that were changed will be compiled;

5. If you have multiple styles functions, I'd recommend to create new one (so you would not break your previous work routine), and test how this new one feels.

P.S Because we use `since.lastRun` -> it will work correctly only after first run. So it's like **compile everything > wait for changes > check changes > compile only edited ones**

P.P.S If you have any questions, I would be happy to answer them.

Comment: Thanks you!! It's a little hard to tell if it's working on my current setup, but it's compiling ~14 stylesheets in less than 1 second. I'm using merged streams and watcher 'on' events so perhaps that's conflicting but actually I should be able to make my setup a lot simplier now with the above.

Comment: I'm glad that my answer helped you.

I recently stumbled on same problem with my gulp setup, so I'm happy that all my research was not completely wasted :)

Comment: Hmm unfortunately "since: gulp.lastRun(styles)" only seems to care about the top-level SCSS files (which have all the imports), if a partial is changed it doesn't pick it up. Same problem gulp-cached too :(

Comment: @Kehza yes, that's why we use `gulp-dependents` -> which tracks all changes in imported files together with `lastRun` instead of `gulp-cached` .

If you were following path described in linked article, correct plugin structure are at the end.

Comment: Hmm I did use gulp-dependents and lastRun but it only seemed to care when my top-level SCSS files changed. e.g. blog.scss, and none of its imported styles or partials. My equivalent of "paths.styles.src" only contains the top-level files e.g. blog.scss and none of its partials. Does that need to change?

Comment: `"paths.styles.src" only contains the top-level files e.g. blog.scss and none of its partials. Does that need to change?`

yes, that need to change, because there are no inner files in pipeline -> thus no dependents tree ;( 

--- 
In my config I have path like this `styles/**/*.scss`